# Building a data analysis report with Oracle and Report Studio

Tags: oracle11g, cognos

I have used information on this site for awhile, and now have a large project that I need some of your expertise on. I work within an Oracle 11g environment and also have Cognos Report Studio 10.1

I am building a multitab report that displays an analysis of a department's outbound orders. I have created a custom table that holds approximately 30 columns of data. From here, there are over 150 calculations that must be performed on the table daily. An example of these calculations are 
1) How many orders received today? 
 
2) Of the orders received today, how many shipped same day? 
 
3) How many orders are on hold?

Basically 100s of 4-5 line queries on the core table. I have thought about creating a second table and with the use of WITH clauses, performing the calculations in a procedure and inserting into the table.

To get to the question, has anyone written a procedure/package that performed a large amount of calculations and is there any links/webpages that can be suggested? My searches have not led me to any examples of a report of this nature being created and am wanting to make sure that my approach is as efficient as possible. Thanks in advance for any information/resources.

Comment: How frequently do these values change? How recent does the data in your report have to be? It's pretty standard to pre-calculate data if it is acceptable to be a little out of date.

Comment: These data calculations represent transactions and changes in orders in a day of production and it will hold one months worth of data. So each day the report will need to populate the past data in addition to the current days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A table and stored procedure is a great idea.  Some considerations:
Will you be archiving these facts per day.

Ie, do you want to be able to lookup the orders that were on hold 5 days ago, or is all of the data in the 150 questions only relevant for the current date?

You can have a table with 150 columns, one for each question.  That may make sense if you are archiving data and need one record per day.

The alternative is to create an order fact table with just two or three fields:

```
Fact_Name        VARCHAR2(30)
Order_Fact       NUMBER(10,2)
Last_Update_Date DATE
```

Your oracle stored procedure would query and update the facts one at a time:

```
insert into ORDER_FACTS
select "ORDERS_RECEIVED" fact_name, count(*) order_fact, sysdate
from   ORDER_TABLE
where  rcv_date = trunc(sysdate);

commit;
```

If you are only wanting to keep one record per fact, you would do an update.

If the answer to some of your questions is not a number, you may need to keep a separate table for facts with VARCHAR2 type.

If you like the sound of this solution, I can setup an example procedure tomorrow.

Edit:

Since you are storing 30 days worth of data, I would create the table at the Date detail level, and have 1 column to store each result.  For my example I just included 3 columns so you could get the idea.  First, create the table to hold your order facts.

```
create table order_facts
( DT               DATE,
  ORD_RCV          NUMBER,
  SAME_DAY_SHIPPED NUMBER,
  ON_HOLD          NUMBER);
```

I suggest the DT field stores the date alone.  This will make the table easier to join with your calendar table, which you can use to join these facts to other reports easily if they are based on tables with Calendar in their star schema.

Next, create the procedure to update them:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CALC_ORDER_FACTS ( iDate date := trunc(sysdate), iPurgeDays number := 0)
IS
  ddate DATE;
  dummy DATE;
/*
      Calc_order_facts
      Date          Author  Note
      04/11/2013    XXX     Created this procedure

  Param iDate (optional, default trunc(sysdate)
    Specify Date to calculate order facts for

  Param iPurgeDays number (optional, default 0)
    Specify how many days to retain data.  Data older than iPurgeDays will be deleted.
    If 0, purging is disabled.

*/

BEGIN
    ddate := iDate;

    IF iPurgeDays > 0 THEN
        dbms_output.put_line('Purging data more than ' || to_char(iPurgeDays) || ' days old.');
        begin
            delete ORDER_FACTS
            where DT < trunc(ddate-iPurgeDays);
            commit;
        EXCEPTION
         WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
            dbms_output.put_line('Purge found no data.');
         WHEN OTHERS THEN
            -- Consider logging the error and then re-raise
            dbms_output.put_line('Purged failed, rollling back...');            
            rollback;
        END;
    END IF;

    -- If date does not already exist in table, insert it
    begin
        select dt
        into dummy
        from order_facts
        where dt = ddate;
    EXCEPTION
     WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
        insert into order_facts 
        values (ddate, null, null, null);
        commit;
    END;

    -- ORD_RCV
    -- Calculate Orders received
    update order_facts
    set ord_rcv = 
        (select count(*) ord_rcv
         from ORDER_TABLE
         where rcv_date = ddate)
    where dt = ddate;
    commit;

    -- SAME_DAY_SHIPPED
    -- Calculate Orders received and shipped on ddate
    update order_facts
    set same_day_shipped = 
          (select count(*) same_day_shipped
           from order_table
           where rcv_dt = ddate
           and ship_dt = ddate)
    where dt = ddate;
    commit;

    -- ON_HOLD
    -- Total orders on_hold
    -- This method applies if you are only concerned with total on hold
    update order_facts
    set on_hold = 
          (select count(*) ON_HOLD
           from order_table
           where status = 'HOLD')
    where dt = ddate;
    commit;

END CALC_ORDER_FACTS;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I will have to hold 30 days worth of calculations so the plan was to perform the calculations on day 1 and add a column equal to SYSDATE to timestamp when they were performed. This would be to allow me to do the calculations on day 2 and display both days in a crosstab query.

Comment: Just to clarify, the report is a collection of crosstab queries in which the horizontal value is the date the calculations are performed. All calculations are relevant to the date to track the performance of a business unit. This report will display 30 days worth of data at a time.

Comment: Added Procedure in Answer.

Comment: Your example is excellent, I didn't think to create a row with current date and then update the attributes. This seems to be a solid solution. I'm going to attempt to set the purge to function that recognizes a change in month and then save the data in the facts table to a flat file before deleting and starting a new month. Thank you for your help.

Comment: That sounds like a great purging solution.  I recommend using a Calendar table to simply your purging logic.  This will be very important if you are going off a fiscal calendar.